# Can't get intended output i.e reversed of hello world after second instance

Tags: python, string

```
class rev(str):
    def __str__(self):
        return self[::-1]

def main():
    s=rev('Hello World.')
    print(s)
    print(s+str(7*7))


if __name__=='__main__': main()
```

Comment: note that `s.__str__()` does provide what you want when called directly. So I guess the question is whether `print` calls `__str__`

Comment: if you call `str(s)`, you do get `.dlrow olleH`. Is that enough that I could write it as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

You have subclassed `str` and overridden the `__str__` method, but that doesn't automatically override all the other methods. `self` is still the forward string — you've just changed how it prints in strings. So in this example, you could override `__add__()` as well to get the desired effect :

```
class rev(str):
    def __str__(self):
        return self[::-1]

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return str(self) + other
        else:
            return NotImplemented



def main():
    s=rev('Hello World.')

    print(s)
    # .dlroW olleH

    print(s+str(7*7))
    # .dlroW olleH49

main()
```

Comment: ooh, nice one! I was wondering whether `print` might be not calling `__str__()` for classes that inherit of str. But that makes more sense - the problem being that the addition happens on self like normally

Comment: This is a solution. but  being new to python, I am still wondering __str__(self) should return a reversed string which is stored in a variable and now we are using this reversed string for   print(s+str(7*7)).